# Bash Script to convert all flv file in a directory to mp3

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, whitespace

This is my code so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
#James Kenaley
#Flv to Mp3 directory converter

find /home/downloads -iname "*.flv" | \
while read I;
do
    `ffmpeg -i ${I} -acodec copy  ${I/%.flv/.mp3}`
    echo "$I has been converted"
done
```

but its picking up white spaces in the names of the flv files and throws a error saying its not in the directory. how do make it use the whole file name and not the just the first word before the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg runs in forked threads, so simple batching can give weird behaviours.  If you are running ffmpeg in the suggested batch loop, you should control your command and command-error output, so that it doesn't interfere.

If you run this and are getting every other item converted properly, but errors on the rest, try using this ffmpeg call in the loop:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "${I}" -acodec mp3 -ar 22050 -f wav "${I/%.3gp/.mp3}" > /dev/null & 2> /dev/null
```

Notice the > dev/null & 2> /dev/null on the end.  This pipes the command output, and command error output into oblivion.  Then the script works.

One should note too that the program output will look strangely disorganized, with multiple files compressing at the same time.  The results will be correct.

[EDIT: NOTE THE -y THAT I HAVE,  THIS MAKES FFMPEG OVERWRITE EXISTING MP3 FILES]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
`ffmpeg -i "${I}" -acodec copy  "${I/%.flv/.mp3}"`
```

Comment: it works but now an even more puzzling thing happens...it converts two files then stops.

Comment: Huh... No idea. I'd sprinkle some `echo` statements to see exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes. And don't use backquotes.

```
ffmpeg -i "${I}" -acodec copy  "${I%.flv}".mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Either call a short script, to do conversion and renaming in one pass:

adhoc.sh:

```
$file="$1"
ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec copy "${file/%.flv/.mp3}"
```

call it:

```
find /home/downloads -iname "*.flv" -exec ./adhoc.sh {} ";" -ls
```

or convert:

```
find /home/downloads -iname "*.flv" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -acodec copy {}.mp3 ";" -ls
```

and rename later:

```
rename 's/.flv.mp3/.mp3/' /home/downloads/*.flv.mp3
```

Rename is part of a perl package which might need installation.